# Include space from input

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace

My user wants an input field where he can enter a message, which I will then have displayed as a scrolling marquee across the page. He wants to be able to include empty spaces, for example,

"Employees       please look up."

My textarea, when I get the text, doesn't notice the space. Any way to get that?

I know this is an odd request - google only tells me how to remove whitespace, not include it.

```js
var text = $('textarea').val();
```

```html
<textarea class='messageInput'></textarea>
```

Comment: The markup of the output (= the "marquee") would also be useful. Is it another textarea, a div element, ...? Because that's what it depends on whether a pure CSS solution is possible or JS is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are getting the value with all the white-spaces right, the problem is in the displaying of the value in your (probably) custom div. The best way would be to set `white-space: pre` on that element which (as the option suggests) will `pre`serve white-space. ;) Example:

```
<div id="foo" style="white-space: pre"><!-- insert text here --></div>
```

And ignore all the `&nbps;` suggestions which are essentially modifying the text content. CSS is the right way to do this!

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert space characters into non-breaking spaces, `&nbsp;` which can be done using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```js
$('#text').html($('textarea').val().replace(/ /g, '&nbsp'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='messageInput'>employees     hello</textarea>
<p id="text"></p>
```

You need `/ /g` so that it will match all spaces, not just the first one, which `.replace(' '...)` would do.

Note that smajl's suggestion is less invasive and probably better, but I'll leave this for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in the value are not ignored. It's that the browser by default "compresses" duplicate spaces. Use `white-space:pre;`

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">
  TEST
</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var content = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(content);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content;
}
```

```css
#result {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">
  TEST
</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

EDIT: too late ;)